# How to express a function in terms of singularity functions?

Tags: calculus

This is the question from the domain of the operational calculus related to circuit analysis. Here is the graph of the sawtooth function:

[image]

It is asked to represent this function as a combination of singularity functions: unit step, unit impulse or unit ramp function. Also, the author postulates that this function is the result of the multiplication of ramp and gate function and gives the following solution:

[image]

I am particularly perplexed by this transformation:

```
5tu(t-2) = 5(t-2+2)u(t-2) = 5(t-2)u(t-2) - 10u(t-2).
```

What is the logic behind?

And more general question. The author proposes another much simpler for the understanding method, namely express the given function as a sum of singularity functions: ramp (0 < t < 2), ramp (t > 2) and unit step (t = 2). Also, which method is normally used by electrical engineers?

Comment: Just a calculus trick to help further down the road: `t = t+0 = t-0 = t-2+2`. It uses `2` which is the delay of the second unit step.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, the word "trick" is the key issue here! Is there any standard procedure which allows to decompose any function to a sum of singularity function?

Comment: It's not a "trick". It's a standard method of manipulating and simplifying an algebraic expression.You will find similar versions in most books on algebra or calculus.

Comment: @PeterJennings You say "standard", I learned "trick" going back tens of years in school. It may be a matter of semantics (debating would lead nowhere), but both reduce to the same thing: re-arranging terms for a better result.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen "trick", "standard method", call it what you will, it's just that the OP was querying the method and asking for a "standard procedure". As far as I'm concerned, the "standard procedure" **is** to apply "tricks" as appropriate and experience will determine which ones to use.

Answer (score 1):

The term 5(t-2)u(t-2) gives you the ramp starting at 2.  Subtracting this term from the original ramp (starting at 0) flattens it out at 10.

The term 10u(t-2) removes that offset of 10, starting at t=2, so that the original function goes back to 0 when t>2.